# error:'isolate' undefined near line 7 column 7

Tags: octave

I have a PROBLEM WITH THIS CODE exactly in the line 7 (isolate).Please someone can read this code and help me to fix the problem.Zhen I run my code they tell me that there's an error in the line 7 column 7.

````
eqn = m*a == -m*g*sin(theta);

syms r
eqn = subs(eqn,a,r*diff(theta,2));

eqn = isolate(eqn,diff(theta,2));

syms omega_0
eqn = subs(eqn,g/r,omega_0^2);

syms x
approx = taylor(sin(x),x,'Order',2);
approx = subs(approx,x,theta(t));

eqnLinear = subs(eqn,sin(theta(t)),approx);

syms theta_0 theta_t0
theta_t = diff(theta);
cond = [theta(0) == theta_0, theta_t(0) == theta_t0];
assume(omega_0,'real')
thetaSol(t) = dsolve(eqnLinear,cond);

gValue = 9.81;
rValue = 1;
omega_0Value = sqrt(gValue/rValue);
T = 2*pi/omega_0Value;

theta_0Value  = 0.1*pi; % Solution only valid for small angles.
theta_t0Value = 0;      % Initially at rest. 

vars   = [omega_0      theta_0      theta_t0];
values = [omega_0Value theta_0Value theta_t0Value];
thetaSolPlot = subs(thetaSol,vars,values);

fplot(thetaSolPlot(t*T)/pi, [0 5]);
grid on;
title('Pendulum Motion');
xlabel('t/T');
ylabel('\theta/\pi'); 

x_pos = sin(thetaSolPlot);
y_pos = -cos(thetaSolPlot);
fanimator(@fplot,x_pos,y_pos,'ko','MarkerFaceColor','k','AnimationRange',[0 5*T]);
hold on;
fanimator(@(t) plot([0 x_pos(t)],[0 y_pos(t)],'k-'),'AnimationRange',[0 5*T]);
fanimator(@(t) text(-0.3,0.3,"Timer: "+num2str(t,2)+" s"),'AnimationRange',[0 5*T]); ```
````

Comment: Please do not tag spam. Read the descriptions of [tag:octave] and [tag:matlab]. Only use both tags if you are asking about differences or similarities between the two languages, otherwise, just use the tag of the language you are working with (I presume that's Octave here). Solutions valid in one language might be invalid in the other.

Comment: “there's an error in the line 7 column 7”. The error text is important. Please co put-paste the full error. You also need to create the shortest program that reproduces the error ([mre]). Since the error happens on line 7, all subsequent lines of code are irrelevant to your question, and just make it harder to help you.